# Bootstrap : Form controls not responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created an html UI for my angular application and unfortunately it is not responsive. When I minimize the screen, the controls fall outside of the window. Could somebody tell me what am i doing wrong

Screenshot - modal window when opened in normal window size

[image]

Screenshot - modal window when opened with minimized window size

[image]

Code

```
<style>
    .desc-header {
        background-color: #FAE7D6;
        color: black
    }

    .header {
        width: 8%;
    }


    .panel-heading {
        color: white;
        background-color: #F59850;
        border-color: #ddd;
    }

    .scrollClass {
        height: 800px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;


    }
</style>



<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Details</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px;">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }">
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div *ngIf="FundDetails" class="card-body" style="width:100%">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-form-label modal-label header">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.Entity.NAME}}</div>
                        <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                            [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.Entity.NAME" />
                    </div>

                    <label for="inputOffice" class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label header">Investment Status</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.InvestmentStatus.NAME}}</div>
                        <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%"
                            [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.Entity.INVESTMENT_STATUS_ID"
                            [data]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatuses" [filterable]="false" textField="NAME"
                            [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2 col-form-label header">Make Anonymous</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.Entity.IS_ANONYMOUS ? "Yes" : "No"}}</div>
                    <label *ngIf="EditMode"> <input type="checkbox" [checked]="FundDetails.Entity.IS_ANONYMOUS"
                            value="{{FundDetails.Entity.IS_ANONYMOUS}}" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.Entity.IS_ANONYMOUS"
                            style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;{{FundDetails.Entity.IS_ANONYMOUS ? "Yes" : "No"}}</label>
                </div>


                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label header">Flagship</label>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.FlagShipFund?.NAME}}</div>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%"
                        [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.Entity.FLAGSHIP_FUND_ID" [data]="FundDetails.FlagshipFunds"
                        [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="inputFax" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Inception Date</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{formatInceptionDate}}</div>
                    <kendo-datepicker *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [format]="'dd MMM, yyyy'" [(ngModel)]="getInceptionDate">
                    </kendo-datepicker>
                </div>


                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label header">Account Mandate</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.AccountMandate?.NAME}}</div>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%"
                        [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.Entity.ACCOUNT_MANDATE_ID" [data]="FundDetails.AccountMandates"
                        [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label header">Vehicle Type</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.VehicleType.NAME}}</div>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%"
                        [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.Entity.VEHICLE_TYPE_ID" [data]="FundDetails.VehicleTypes"
                        [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>


                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label header">Bloomberg Ticker</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.Entity.BLOOMBERG_TICKER}}</div>
                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.Entity.BLOOMBERG_TICKER" />
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label header">Primary Class</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.PrimaryClasses.DESCRIPTION}}</div>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%"
                        [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.Entity.PRIMARY_CLASS_ID" [data]="FundDetails.Classes"
                        [filterable]="false" textField="DESCRIPTION" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>



            </div>



            <!-- Flagship needs to be disable based on user role -->
            <div class="form-group row">




            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">

                <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 30px;">
                    <div class="desc-header">Details</div>
                    <div class="divEditor">
                        <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [id]="'ckDetails'" *ngIf="EditMode" style="font-size: 11px;"
                            debounce="500" [config]="EditorConfig"
                            [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.Entity.ACCOUNT_MANDATE_CUSTOMISATION">
                        </ckeditor>
                        <div style="padding: 10px" *ngIf="!EditMode"
                            [innerHTML]="FundDetails.Entity.ACCOUNT_MANDATE_CUSTOMISATION">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>





        </div>
        <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">


            <span *ngIf="EditMode"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                    (click)="saveManager()">Save</button>

            </span>
            <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                    (click)="cancelManager">Cancel</button>
            </span>
            <span><button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all"
                    (click)="deleteManager()">Delete</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using tables for layout rather than the Bootstrap grid system?

Comment: I would highly reccomend you don't use tables for layout, Bootstrap has a very good grid system you can use for layout. Looking at your HTML however its likley the fixed width you have is causing the issue - try changing it to a % or auto i.e. `<kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.InvestmentStatus" [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.InvestmentStatuses"
                                        [filterable]="false" textField="Name" valueField="Id"></kendo-dropdownlist>`

Comment: removing fixed width works but thinking of using the grid system as you suggested. Could you show me an example of atleast one row using the grid styles please. You know how my UI looks

Comment: Sorry I wasnt using table as I just updated the post. I had initially posted the wrong html